# How many times do I have to roll a die to get six six times in a row?

Tags: probability, simulation, approximation, dice

I wonder if there's any exact way to find out these two things about six-sided dice:

1. How many throws would be necessary to get six times the same number (let's say six) in a row?
2. What's the probability of getting six times the same number (again, let's say six) in a row within 100 throws?

I wrote a simple simulation program in C and tried it on $100*2^{20}$ numbers, but I want to  compare my numbers and see if I can skip the programming part in future.

For the first question, I got number around $54160$, and for the second one it was $1861/1048576 \approx 0.001775$. I was told that my numbers should be smaller and bigger respectively. Is there any chance for my numbers to be OK? Otherwise it would mean that I made a mistake in my code.

Comment: Concerning question 1: Do these help: [First](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27989/time-until-a-consecutive-sequence-of-ones-in-a-random-bit-sequence/27991#27991), [second](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192177/how-many-times-to-roll-a-die-before-getting-two-consecutive-sixes)?

Comment: Question 1 is like asking "how large is a normally distributed random variable", which is nonsense. Maybe you are interested in the distribution the waiting time or maybe just its average?

Comment: Q: How many times?  ANSWER:  a lot.

Comment: The multiple answers at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12174/time-taken-to-hit-a-pattern-of-heads-and-tails-in-a-series-of-coin-tosses provide several approaches to tackles questions like this.

Comment: You realize that you'll have different numbers of throws to get "6" size times and to get any side six times?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a way to get the exact answer.

---

Definition & Notation:

$X_i$: number of throw to get the same number (let say 6) in $i$ consecutive rolls,

$\mu_i = E(X_i)$, that is the expected number of roll; $\mu_6$ is what we want.

$D$: Indicator of whether get the number we desire (6 in this case) in one throw, 1 for success, 0 for fail. It is clearly that $D \sim Bernoulli(p)$.

$p$: the probability of getting the number (6) we desire

Let's us start from the simplest case $i=1$, the number of throw to get one 6. Some of you may quickly realised that
$$\mu_1 = \frac{1}{p}$$

In fact, when $i=1$, we are doing a sequence of independent bernoulli trial until we make the first success (get one 6) and $X_1$ is the number of trial needed until the first, which follows a geometric distribution[$^1$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricDistribution.html)[$^2$](http://www.randomservices.org/random/bernoulli/Geometric.html)[$^3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter $p$, and its mean is $\frac{1}{p}$.

So, how about $i\ge2$? In order to get r consecutive 6's in die rolling, we must get (r-1) consecutive 6's first. At that moment we have 2 scenarios:

1. We get a 6 in the next throw and end
2. We don't get a '6' and keep playing with our die until we get r consecutive 6's

As you will see, the number of throw is $X_{r-1}+1$ in the first scenario, and $X_{r}+1+X_{r}$ in another. Don't forget that you have the count the throw right after you get (r-1)-time 6's, so we have '+1' when we calculate both counts. Combining them, we have

$$X_r = X_{r-1} + 1 + (1-D)X_r$$

Using double expectation:
$$\mu_r = E(X_r) = E\left[E(X_r|D)\right]$$
$$\implies \mu_r = pE\left[E(X_r|D=1)\right] + (1-p)E\left[E(X_r|D=0)\right]$$
Since
$$(X_r|D=1) = X_{r-1} + 1 \implies E(X_r|D=1) = \mu_{r-1} + 1$$
$$(X_r|D=0) = X_{r-1} + 1 + X_r \implies E(X_r|D=0) = \mu_{r-1} + 1 + \mu_r$$
we have
$$\mu_r = p[\mu_{r-1}+1] + (1-p)[\mu_{r-1} + 1 + \mu_r]$$
After some rearrangement, we will get the following relationship:
$$\mu_r = \frac{\mu_{r-1}+1}{p}$$

If we are playing a fair die (i.e. $p=\frac{1}{6}$), we will obtain $\mu_6 = 55986$.

Now, we relax our criteria, let say any number (either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) appears six times in a row. The answer is truly smaller than 55986 because you can six 1's before getting six 6's. To calculate the expected number of throw, same logic used above still apply:

$Y_i$: number of throw to get the same number (either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) in $i$ consecutive rolls,

$\theta_i = E(Y_i)$, that is the expected number of roll; $\theta_6$ is what we want.

$D_x$: Indicator of getting $x$, $x\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

First, we have $\theta_1=1$ this time. The reason is obvious, when we throw a die, we must get a number from {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} and end rolling the die afterwards, the count ($X_1$) must be 1, also $\mu_1$, unless you are not playing a 6-sided die or the die disappeared after you throw it etc.

And for $r \ge 2$, let's go back to the scenario of getting $x$ (r-1)-time

1. We get a $x$ in the next throw and end
2. We don't get a $x$ but $y$, $y \ne x$, keep playing with our die until we get r consecutive $y$

For scenario 1, only ($Y_{r-1}+1$) rolls are needed, but for another scenario, we need ($Y_{r-1}+Y_r$). Be noted that no '+1' is needed here because when a different number $y$ shows up, we are attempt to get $r$ consecutive $y$, the 'first' roll is included in $Y_r$ here. Then, the following can be derived:

$$Y_r = D_x(Y_{r-1}+1) + (1-D_x)(Y_{r-1}+Y_r), x \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

If we are playing a **FAIR** die, the recursive relation can be generalized as
$$Y_r = X_{r-1} + (1-D)Y_r$$

where $D$ is the indicator of getting the same number as last throw given that we are playing a fair die, $Pr(D=1)=\frac{1}{6}$.

After all, the following can be derived,
$$\theta_r = 6\theta_{r-1}+1$$

Applying the formula, $\theta_6 = 9331$ will be obtained under the looser criteria (fair die). (Credit to [Aksakal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/36041/aksakal) for pointing out my mistake).

---

For the second question, we can make use of the transition matrix $M$
$$M = \left[\begin{matrix}
\text{stage} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
0 & \frac{5}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
3 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0\\
4 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0\\
5 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6}\\
6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

where stage $i$ means we currently have $i$ consecutive '6' and we assume that we are playing a fair die.

The entries of the matrix are the probability of getting from one stage (row) to one stage (column). If we die once; for example, from stage 6 to stage 6, the probability is 1 (because we have achieved our goal)

By the properties of transition matrix, $M^k$ is the transition matrix of rolling the die k-time. Therefore, we can calculate $M^{100}$ and value in the first row and the last column will be the probability of going to stage 6 from stage 0 after 100-time of roll dicing, that is your answer. (it is 0.001699134)

If we loosen our criteria to any number six times in a row, our transition matrix will become

$$M = \left[\begin{matrix}
\text{stage} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & \frac{5}{6}& \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0\\
4 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0\\
5 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6}\\
6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

---

For question 1 (six consecutive '6'), there is another way of think (which is my original answer) but similar approach. It will yield a slightly different result and the reason is still unknown. Any discussion are all welcome.

Definition & Notation:

stage $i$: the moment that we have $i$ 6 in a row

$X_i$: the random variable of no. of rolls needed in stage $i$ in order to get "6" six times

$\mu_i = E(X_i)$, in this case, $\mu_0$ is our answer.

Suppose we have now diced $n$-times and get five 6's in a row (stage $5$) and roll the die again. If we get a 6, we achieve our goal and the count of rolling is $n+1$; otherwise, we go back to stage $0$ and $(1 + X_0)$-time will be needed to archive our goal. Thus, the expected value of $X_5$ ($\mu_5$) will be
$$\mu_5 = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6}(1+\mu_0) = 1 + \frac{5}{6}\mu_0$$

Now, consider we have four 6's in a row (stage $4$). If we get a 6 next, we proceed to stage $5$, that means we have to roll $(1+X_5)$-time more; otherwise, we are back to stage $0$. Thus,
$$\mu_4 = 1 + \frac{1}{6}\mu_5 + \frac{5}{6}\mu_0$$

Following the same logic, the followings will be obtained:
$$\mu_3 = 1 + \frac{1}{6}\mu_4 + \frac{5}{6}\mu_0$$
$$\mu_2 = 1 + \frac{1}{6}\mu_3 + \frac{5}{6}\mu_0$$
$$\mu_1 = 1 + \frac{1}{6}\mu_2 + \frac{5}{6}\mu_0$$
$$\mu_0 = 1 + \frac{1}{6}\mu_1 + \frac{5}{6}\mu_0$$

So, we get a system of linear equations:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\frac{5}{6} & -1 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\frac{5}{6} & 0 & -1 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\ 
\frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & -1 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 \\ 
\frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & \frac{1}{6} \\ 
\frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}\mu_0 \\ \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \\ \mu_3 \\ \mu_4 \\ \mu_5\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}1\\ -1\\ -1\\ -1\\ -1\\ 1\end{matrix}\right]
\implies
\left[\begin{matrix}\mu_0 \\ \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \\ \mu_3 \\ \mu_4 \\ \mu_5\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}55974\\ 55968\\ 55932\\ 55716\\ 54420\\ 46644\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Comment: +1. There has to be a mistake (probably a typo) concerning the first question: When I solve the linear equation system as given in the answer, I get different numbers: $55974, 55968, 55932, 55716, 54420, 46644$.

Comment: Oh yes, I got a typo in my code of calculation. The solution of the system should be (55974, 55968, 55932, 55716, 54420, 46644)

Comment: Also, the answer of question 2 is 0.001699134 (if I calculate it correctly)

Comment: That'a what I got (for the second question). Just out of curiosity: How do you explain the discrepancy between your answer to question 1 and the answer we get when we apply the formulas in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192177/how-many-times-to-roll-a-die-before-getting-two-consecutive-sixes) (by Byron Schmuland)? Using $p=\frac{1}{6}$ and $n=6$, I get $\left(\frac{1}{6}^{-6}-1\right)/(\frac{5}{6})=55\,986$ which differs from your answer of $55\,974$.

Comment: I am still thinking why there is difference but still no conclusion. However, when I modified the definition of $X_i$, and follow similar logic, the formula you used was derived

$$X_i \text{: no. of rolls to get }i\text{ consecutive 6's}$$

$$p = Pr(\text{get a 6}) $$

$$\mu_1 = 6$$
$$\mu_2 = \mu_1 + p + (1-p)(1+\mu_2)$$
$$\mu_3 = \mu_2 + p + (1-p)(1+\mu_3)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\mu_k = \mu_{k-1} + p + (1-p)(1+\mu_k)$$

$$\implies \mu_k = \frac{\mu_{k-1}+1}{p}$$

Comment: And one point to add, if you want to find out the expected number of throws to get six times the same number (either 1,2,3,4,5,6) in a row; the above formula/solution will be inappropriate.

Comment: @kitman0804, you are not answering OP's question 1. OP is not asking how many throws *in average*. So, maybe you should start with reformulating the question. Even more important, OP is asking two different questions in Q1: one is about any side and one is about side 6. They'll have different answers.

Comment: @Aksakal Thanks for your comment. I do believe that OP is asking about the average number of throws, not the 'necessary' number of throws which is 6 (maybe OP need to clarify it). Also, I have noticed that OP is also asking about any side six times, I have mentioned that the answer will be different in this case but did not provide the answer. I will add it soon.

Comment: @kitman0804, I don't think your answer for six of any side is right. It's got to be 1/6 of the 6 of 6. Somthing like ~9K

Comment: @Aksakal You are right. Thanks again for pointing my mistake.

Comment: Sorry for renewing after 3 years, I'm the OP. Got an offer to study mathematics at uni! How soon will I be able to understand all of the above? :P (e. g. during bachelors, masters or ...?)

Answer (score 6):

Regarding question 1, there is a very simple and elegant way to obtain a result via Martingale Theory (refer to the best (in my humble opinion) introductory book on the subject [Probability with Martingales](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521406056) chapter 10 section 11). The proof requires hardly any calculations and is done in 3 steps provided that you use several martingale theory results (Doob's optional stopping time theorem in particular). Look it up!

QUESTION: What is the expected time for a monkey to type **ABRACADABRA** on a typewriter, provided that you only have 26 keys (the letters of the alphabet) and his typing is random (so 1/26 chances of producing any given letter at any time?
Try solving this with standard recursive methods!

ANSWER:
$E\left ( T \right ) = 26^{11} + 26^{4} + 26$

Had the chain been ABCDEFGHIJK it would have required (26^11), so although this might seem counter-intuitive, randomly producing chains that have symmetry or a repetitve pattern takes longer on average.

The general rule is the following:

$E\left ( T \right )= \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\left ( \frac{1}{p} \right )^{k}\times I_{pattern}\left ( n - k + 1 \right )$

where **n** is the length of the chain, **p** the probability of typing any given character, and

$$
I_{pattern}(k) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if pattern(j) $=$ pattern(k + j - 1) } \forall j \in \left \{1,...,n-k+1\right \}\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

In your case, since the pattern is simply a repitition of 6s, the average time (i.e. average number of rolls) is  $6^{6} + 6^{5} + ... + 6$