# PMF of the number of trials required for two successive heads

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics, probability-generating-fn

> A coin with probability $p$ of landing a head is tossed repeatedly till the occurrence of two consecutive heads. Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the the number of trials needed. What is the distribution of $X$?

We consider a partition of the sample space where the sequence of events begins with a $T$, an $HT$ and an $HH$.  So we have,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X)&=\mathbb{E}(X\mid T)\mathbb{P}(T)+\mathbb{E}(X\mid HT)\mathbb{P}(HT)+\mathbb{E}(X\mid HH)\mathbb{P}(HH)
\\&=\mathbb{E}(X+1)q+\mathbb{E}(X+2)pq+2p^2\qquad,\,q=1-p
\end{align}

Thus in general for a function $g$ we have,

$$\mathbb{E}(g(X))=\mathbb{E}(g(X+1))q+\mathbb{E}(g(X+2))pq+g(2)p^2$$

Let $g(X)=t^X$, so that we get the PGF of $X$ as

\begin{align}
P(t)=\mathbb{E}(t^X)&=tqP(t)+t^2pqP(t)+t^2p^2
\\&=p^2t^2(1-qt-pqt^2)^{-1}
\end{align}

Now to get the p.m.f. of $X$ I need to find the coefficient of $t^j$ in the expansion of $P(t)$.

$$P(t)=p^2t^2(1-qt(1+pt))^{-1}=p^2t^2\sum_{j=0}^\infty(qt(1+pt))^j\,,$$

assuming $|qt(1+pt)|<1$.

But I could not separate the $t^j$ and its coefficient in the above expression.

Comment: One way is to expand $(1 - qt - qpt^2)^{-1}$ as partial fractions: their coefficients are given directly by the Binomial theorem.

Comment: A similar post is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12174/time-taken-to-hit-a-pattern-of-heads-and-tails-in-a-series-of-coin-tosses/24924#24924

Comment: Related answer on math.se: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73772/321264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor $$1 - qt(1+pt) = (1-at)(1-bt)$$ by finding its roots and notice $a\ne b$.  From the resulting partial fraction decomposition

$$(1 - qt(1+pt))^{-1} = \frac{a}{a-b}(1 - a t)^{-1} - \frac{b}{a-b}(1 - b t)^{-1}$$

apply the Binomial Theorem to each of $(1-at)^{-1}$ and $(1-bt)^{-1}$ and combine the series to obtain

$$p^2t^2(1 - qt(1+pt))^{-1} = \frac{p^2}{a-b}\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(a^{i+1} - b^{i+1}\right)t^{i+2}\right).$$

The coefficient of $t^j = t^{i+2}$ for $j\ge 2$ therefore is $$\frac{p^2(a^{j-1}-b^{j-1})}{a-b}.$$

---

These manipulations are fully justified as formal power series in $t$.  But since everything converges absolutely for $|t|\lt \min(1/|a|, 1/|b|)$, there's no problem considering them as analytic functions in a neighborhood of $0$, either.

Comment: Thanks. Can $\mathbb{P}(X=j)$ be found directly, i.e. without resorting to pgf?

Comment: There are several ways, such as representing the process as a Markov chain.  That will yield the probability as an entry in a power of the transition matrix.  The underlying mathematical calculations turn out to be nearly the same, though: finding $a$ and $b$ is replaced by solving the characteristic equation to obtain the eigenvalues and the Binomial Theorem is replaced by diagonalizing the matrix by means of the eigenvectors.  You can also obtain a second order recursive formula, but its solution also is mathematically similar to the one with the pgf.

Answer (score 1):

You have found the pgf (probability generating function) for the waiting time $X$, the least possible value of $X$ is two.  I cannot find a really simple closed form for the pmf (probability mass function), but I will show one possibility.

You found that
$$
   P(t) = p^2 t^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (qt(1+pt))^k
$$
we can start with expanding $(1+pt)^k$ using the binomial theorem, that gives
$$
P(t) = p^2 t^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} p^j q^k t^{j+k}
$$
To be able to read off probabilities, we want to write this such that the power of $t$ is directly the (outer) summation variable. So define $n=j+k$ and rewrite the sum with $n$ as summation variable, but at first $n$ will appear in the inner sum. This gives
$$
P(t)=p^2 t^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{q}{p})^k \sum_{n=k}^{2k} \binom{k}{n-k} p^n t^n 
$$
Finally, we want to change the order of summation. Note that the index $n$ satisfies (from the limits on the inner sum) $n \ge k, n \le 2k$. Solve this inequalities for $k$ to get $k \le n, k \ge n/2$.  Remembering that $k$ must be an integer we write this as $k \le n, k \ge \lceil n/2\rceil$  where the last strange brackets indicate the *ceiling* function, the smallest integer gretare that or equal to its argument (that is, rounding up to closest integer). Using this we finaly get
$$
   P(t) = p^2 t^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=\lceil n/2 \rceil}^n \binom{k}{n-k} (\frac{q}{p})^k p^n t^n
$$
and from that formula we can read off 
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\P(X=n+2) = p^{n+2} \sum_{k=\lceil n/2 \rceil}^n \binom{k}{n-k} (\frac{q}{p})^k
$$
but I dont know about simplifying that last expression.  But, it could be used for small $n$, and then for large $n$ some approximation, maybe a saddlepoint approximation which can use the pgf directly.