# Moment Generating Function for values $t \neq 0$

Tags: moment-generating-function

I'm studying statistics using Rice's Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis.

We can find the $r$th moment of a random variable $X$ by taking the moment generating function $M(t)$ of $X$ and taking the derivative $r$ times. Then substituting $t=0$, we arrive at the $r$the moment. Are moment generating functions significant in any way for values $t \neq 0$?

Comment: Yes. For one, the derivative at zero depends on the values of the MGF in a neighborhood of zero, not just its value at zero.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304066/real-life-uses-of-moment-generating-functions/304069#304069  for examples!