# Match forecasting for games with multiple win conditions

Tags: predictive-models, prediction

I'm trying to make a model for forecasting the results of games with multiple win conditions.

For example, we may have a game where the first player to score a certain number of points wins, or the player with the most points after a time limit is reached wins. Say we have a point limit of 5 and a time limit of 10 minutes. If neither player scores 5 points in 10 minutes, then scores like 3-2 or 1-2 are possible. However, if a player reaches 5 points, then the score may be 5-0 or 5-4 in a shorter amount of time than 10 minutes.

One way of approximating results for this is using a poisson model, estimating ranking variables for each player, then simply censoring predictions that have wins over the limit. A poisson model isn't applicable in this case though, because if the limit is reached then the duration of the game is shorter, so scores of 5-2 should be more likely than 5-4.

Another case I'm interested in is where there is a limit on point difference, rather than absolute number of points.

Are there any existing statistical models that account for multiple win conditions like this?

Comment: One way is to model the probability of winning a point. E.g. for games like tennis/table tennis/volley ball etc the game ends when a score-line is met. For a nice example, see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329521/if-i-have-a-58-chance-of-winning-a-point-whats-the-chance-of-me-winning-a-pin

Your time limit condition makes things a little more complicated and you will have to model the time of games, maybe conditional on the time to score a point, as well.

Comment: This was a helpful comment! I've been trying to model on a point basis- calculating win probabilities of individual points is easy using this method. Calculating the distribution of point durations is more difficult. I have data on this, but by nature, there will be a higher proportion of shorter points with a time limit, any points longer than 10 minutes simply will not be counted.