# Tricky probability questions re Tenis match

Tags: probability, statistical-significance

A tennis match is played as a series of POINTS, contained within GAMES, which in turn are contained within SETS.

If a player reaches 4 or more points won in a game, and also has won 2 points more than their opponent, then they win that game.

If a player reaches 6 or more games won in a set, and also has won 2 games more than their opponent, then they win that set. If both players reach 6 games, then a TIE-BREAK is played to determine the winner of the set.

Suppose Djokovic plays a set of tennis against Murray under these rules, and his probablity of winning a point is 0.48. Assuming the probability of winning a point remains constant throughout, what would be the probability of Djokovic winning the set 7-5?

I do understand the questions but my problem is at a fundamental level of posing the problem so some guideance would be appreciated and yes, I am a total noob

Comment: This is an example of the problem discussed (and solved) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329521/if-i-have-a-58-chance-of-winning-a-point-whats-the-chance-of-me-winning-a-pin/329554#329554.

Comment: It's a different problem. Tennis & ping pong have different scoring systems.