# Probability of winning a competition K games best of series of N games

Tags: r, probability

Consider a 'best of 5' series in sports/competition where the first team to win 3 games wins the series. So N=5, K=3. Where  probability `w = p(team A winning game)` and `l = p(team A losing game)`. Assume these probabilities do not change during the series.

When I first thought about this I mistakenly tried adding the individual probabilities of winning 3/3, 3/4, and 3/5 games:

```
wrong = function(w) {      
  p = dbinom(3,3,w) + dbinom(3,4,w) + dbinom(3,5,w)       
  return(p)
}

wrong(.9)
# 1.0935
```

Obviously, the issue is there is redundancy since 3 wins in a row, W-W-W renders any game 4 and 5 results obsolete. i.e. W-W-W-L-W and W-W-W-W-L aren't possible.

After removing redundancies these are the possible permutations:

```
win = function(w) {
  l = 1-w
  p = w*w*w + 
    w*w*l*w + w*l*w*w + l*w*w*w + 
    l*l*w*w*w+ l*w*l*w*w+ l*w*w*l*w+  
    w*l*l*w*w+ w*l*w*l*w+
    w*w*l*l*w

  return(p)
}

win(.9)
# 0.99144

win(.9) + win(.1)
# 1
```

Manually typing the permutations gets out of hand quickly with longer series i.e. winning a N = 7 game series, 9 game series, etc. Generally, how does `wrong()` function need to be modified to get the correct probability?

Comment: See [existing questions on Math.SE on *probabiltiy win series*](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+win+series+votes%3A5)

Comment: The methods presented in the answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329521 make short work of this question, which is a simplified version of that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) for this problem.

If X is distributed as NegBin(n, w), then X is the number of games the player loses before winning n of them, if the probability of winning any given game is w.

So, `dnbinom(q = 2, size = 2, prob = w)` is the probability that the player loses a total of 2 games before winning 2.

Then, `pnbinom(q = 2, size = 3, prob = w)` is the probability that the player loses 2 or less before they win 3 games. This is equal to the probability of winning a 3 out of 5 series.

In general, the probability of winning a best n-out-of-(2n-1) series can be calculated with `pnbinom(q = n-1, size = n, prob = w)`.

```r
## w is the probability of winning any individual game
## k is the number of wins needed to win the series (3 in a best 3 of 5 series)
win <- function(w, k){
  return (pnbinom(q = k - 1, size = k, prob = w))
}

win(0.9, 3)
## 0.99144
```

Comment: Nice solution using negative binomial distribution, +1! By the way, for generality, i.e.,even or odd `N`, applying `wins_needed <- ceiling((N+1)/2)` enables a generic function `win`

Comment: Thanks for the note @ThomasIsCoding - in this case, N should always be odd, since an even length series can end tied

Comment: I agree though that parameterizing `win` in terms of N opens the door to inputting an even length series. I've changed it to be in terms of k, the wins needed, to address that. Thanks again for the note

Comment: If `N` is even, then you need `ceiling((N+1)/2)` wins to win the serial, e.g., 4 out of 6. In this case, your generic function `win` in terms of `N` can be defined like `win <- function(w, N)  pnbinom(floor((N-1)/2), ceiling((N+1)/2), w)`， which can deal with either odd or even `N`

Answer (score 6):

This is interesting. Let's demonstrate using `n = 3` where it takes 2 wins to be the winner. We can first determine which combinations are available

```
n = 3L
lst = replicate(n, 0:1, simplify = FALSE)
combos = do.call(expand.grid, lst)
combos

  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    0    0    0
2    1    0    0
3    0    1    0
4    1    1    0
5    0    0    1
6    1    0    1
7    0    1    1
8    1    1    1
```

As you noted, some of these combinations are not possible. We are specifically interested when the `rowSums()` are equal to 2. Using this we can figure out which combinations are actually possible.

```
possible_combos = combos[rowSums(combos) == ceiling(n / 2), ]
possible_combos

  Var1 Var2 Var3
4    1    1    0
6    1    0    1
7    0    1    1
```

Our last step is to calculate each contribution from our possible contributions. We know that `w^2` will be in each calculation. The `l` part is more complicated. In our first possible combination, the `l` contributes nothing. We can use `max.col(..., ties.method = "last")` to figure how many `l`s occurred:

```
losses = max.col(possible_combos, ties.method = "last") - ceiling(n / 2)
losses
# [1] 0 1 1

w = 0.9
l = 1 - w
wins_p = w ^ ceiling(n / 2)
losses_p = ifelse(losses == 0L, 1, l ^ losses)

p = sum(wins_p * losses_p)
p
# [1] 0.972
```

To generalize this, we can use this as a function based on `n` and `w`:

```
right = function(n, w) {
  lst = replicate(n, 0:1, simplify = FALSE)
  combos = do.call(expand.grid, lst)
  possible_combos = combos[rowSums(combos) == ceiling(n / 2), ]
  losses = max.col(possible_combos, ties.method = "last") - ceiling(n / 2)

  l = 1 - w
  wins_p = w ^ ceiling(n / 2)
  losses_p = ifelse(losses == 0L, 1, l ^ losses)

  sum(wins_p * losses_p)
}

right(5, 0.9)
# [1] 0.99144
right(5, 0.9) + right(5, 0.1)
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually you are almost there, but you should be aware of the cases with four and five games to win.

```
win <- function(w) dbinom(3,3,w)+w*dbinom(2,3,w) + w*dbinom(2,4,w)
```

or a compact solution

```
win <- function(w) w*sum(mapply(dbinom,2,2:4,w))
```

such that

```
> win(0.9)
[1] 0.99144
```

**Explanation**:
Given that the number of games needed to win the serial depends on the last win:

- If 3 games are needed: the first two should both wins, such that the prob. is `w**3` (equivalently `dbinom(3,3,w)` or `dbinom(2,2,w)*w`)
- If 4 games are needed: among the previous three games there should be 2 wins and 1 loss, such that the prob. is `choose(4,2)*w**2*(1-w)*w` (equivalently `dbinom(2,4,w)*w`)
- If 5 games are needed: among previous four games there should both 2 wins and 2 losses, such that the prob. is `choose(4,2)*w**2*(1-w)**2*w` (equivalently `dbinom(2,4,w)*w`)

---

**Update**: Generalization of `win`

With respect to any `N` (either even or odd), a generalized function `win` can be defined like below

```
win <- function(w, N) w*sum(mapply(dbinom,ceiling((N-1)/2),ceiling((N-1)/2):(N-1),w))
```

However, above is not as efficient for large `N`s. Instead, the negative binomial distribution method mentioned by [@RyanFrost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048065/12158757) is preferred for cases with large `N`s, i.e.,

```
win <- function(w, N) pnbinom(floor((N-1)/2), ceiling((N+1)/2), w)
```

**Example**

```
> win(0.9,5) # needs at 3 wins out of 5 games
[1] 0.99144

> win(0.9,6) # needs at 4 wins out of 6 games
[1] 0.98415
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a binomial distribution:

```
dbinom(3,5,0.9) + dbinom(4,5,0.9)+dbinom(5,5,0.9) = 0.99144
```

The reason goes like this, you just need to think about the total space,  even if there are already 3 wins or 4 wins, let's imagine the event goes on and we can write the possible events to include as:

```
w.w.w : w.w.w.w.k , w.w.w.k.k , w.w.w.k.w, w.w.w.w,w
w.w.l.w : w.w.l.w.l, w.w.w.l.w
l.w.w.w : l.w.w.w.1 , l.w.w.w.w
```

And so on..

And those that have written as containing 3 wins for example (w.w.l.w.l) will be part of 5 choose 3 in a binomial.

Out of the total space of W/L over 5 events, what we need are 3 wins, 4 wins and 5 wins to include all the events that can result in the team winning (even though in real life, the 4th or 5th match will not occur)

Comment: This sum can also be written as `pbinom(5-3, 5, 1-0.9)` or `1 - pbinom(5-3, 5, 0.9)`

Comment: yeah of course, pbinom would work. I just wrote the sum to be clear. Thanks for pointing it out.. I guess not a very good explanation anyway lol

Comment: thanks for edit too !

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function `win` that computes the probability to win `k` out of `n` games with a probability to win each game `w`. It implements the idea of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1759106) Math.SE post.

```
win <- function(w, n = 5, k = 3){
  loose <- function(w, n, k){
    l <- 1 - w
    m <- n - k
    s <- seq_len(n - 1)[-seq_len(m - 1)]
    ch <- sapply(s, function(x) choose(x, m))
    w <- w^(seq_along(s) - 1)
    l^m * sum(w*ch)
  }
  if(k >= ceiling(n / 2)){
    1 - loose(w, n, k)*(1 - w)
  }else{
    stop("a minority cannot win.")
  }
}
win(0.9)
#[1] 0.99144

win(0.1)
#[1] 0.00856

win(0.9) + win(0.1)
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What your're asking is a simple math problem. I'll try to explain the math step by step then we'll write our codes with respect of that.

### Math

**Combination**
In mathematics, a [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) is a selection of items from a collection and is defined as follows.
[image]

 Where `!` is the factorial operator. For example let's assume we have four rounds and you want to select three wins (or one loose). We have:
[image]
Which are: w-w-w-l, w-w-l-w, w-l-w-w, l-w-w-w
But as you mentioned, w-w-w-l is not acceptable because the game is done when 3 wins are accomplished! So take a good look at this point:

> If our rounds takes more than 3 (best of 5), the last one must be win if winning probability calculation is desired!

So to correct my calculations I should first select the last round as a win and select 2 other spots (from remaining spots) for winning. Or
[image]

And if we show winning probability with `w` and loosing with `l` the probability of this state to be happened is

[image]

### Javascript

Now that you know the concept, let's begin coding!
First I need a function to calculate factorial of n (`n!`).

```
let f = (n)=>
{
    let o = 1;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        o *= i;
    }
    return o;
}
```

To understand the procedure better, I'll write my codes step by step. So the next step is to define the combination function.

```
let c = (n,r)=>
{
    return f(n)/(f(r) * f(n-r));
}
```

And now it's time to calculate `r` wins probability in a `p` round game with win probability of `w`.

```
let _w = (p,r,w)=>
{
    let o = 1;
    // Selection of win positions
    o *= c(1,1) * c(p-1,r-1);
    // Calculation probability
    o *= Math.pow(w, r) * Math.pow(1-w, p-r);

    return o;
}
```

Now we are ready to make the `BO` (Best Of) function with N rounds and K wins.

```
let BO = (N, K, w)=>
{
    // P is what we wish to find!
    let P = 0;
    for (j=K; j<=N; j++)
    {
        P += _w(j, K, w);
    }
    return P;
}
```

And some examples:

```
console.log(BO(5,3,0.9)); // 0.9914400000000001
console.log(BO(7,4,0.9)); // 0.997272
console.log(BO(9,5,0.9)); // 0.99910908
```