# How do I calculate the probability of winning with any result?

Tags: probability, distributions

How do I calculate the probability of winning with any result?

Data:

- A match can last a maximum of 30 rounds
- The team that scores 16 rounds first wins a match
- The match may end with a score of 15-15
- Team A has 60% probability to score a round
- Team A has 40% probability to score a round

Comment: Please add `self-study` tag and show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Did you intend for last two bullets to be exactly the same?

Comment: The same game, with slightly more complicated termination rules, is analyzed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329521.

Comment: You could use a binomial distribution with $n=30$