# What is the probability TT shows up before TH?

Tags: probability

A coin tossed repeatedly with P(H)=p and P(T)=1-p, What is the probability TT shows up before TH?

Comment: I don't know this stackexchange's policy on homework, so I'll give hints.  What are the possible sequences leading up to TT or TH, but not including either one?  Are these sequences different?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12174/ and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/544811 for some methods.